# Dog peeing in the house while we are outside

Tags: dogs, behavior

My nine year old pit bull keeps barking and peeing in the house while my husband and I are outside doing yard work. She is not crate trained and is usually well behaved. Please help!

Comment: Welcome to Pets.Se Natalia! Please check out the answers provided in the questions attached to yours, you should be able to find your answer :)